# Handling common code between different activities, fragments, tasks, etc

Tags: java, android, class, oop, singleton

I have quite some (not too much, but quite some) experience with Java and object-oriented programming in other languages, but am fairly new to Android and my understanding of all its different classes is at best described as *limited* (more realistic would be *confused*).

I'm creating an application that for now consists of one activity and a widget. One of its functionality will be fetching some data from the internet. This data will only change every day on some arbitrary moment, so there's no need to fetch this data every time you start the app or look at the widget.

My problem is that I'd like to have one method to fetch the data and store it in shared preferences, together with the update time (so that it's only updated once a day). This method has to be accessible from the widget and the activity.

Normally I would simply create some class with a static method to do this. However, to access the shared preferences you need a `Context`. I can come up with two ways:

#### Option 1: static method, `Context` as parameter

```
public class MyClass {
    public static String fetchData(Context context) {
        return // ...
    }
}
```

#### Option 2: singleton

```
public class MyClass {
    private static MyClass instance = null;
    private Context context;

    public MyClass(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String fetchData() {
        return ...;
    }

    public static MyClass getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new MyClass(context);
        return instance;
    }

    public static MyClass getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Now I would call it with `MyClass.getInstance(getActivity()).fetchData()` the first time, and after that `MyClass.getInstance().fetchData()`.

### My question

Is either of these preferred over the other, and if so, why? Or is there another, better, way to do this kind of thing? Or does it depend on the situation (and in that case, on what precisely?)?

Later, I may have more of these methods. Since the Context is something that normally doesn't change, I thought a singleton may be useful here because after the first instantiation you don't need to give a context anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 is ok to use almost all the time. Option 2 is dangerous because you are keeping a reference to a `Context`. if the `Context` is of type `Activity` you can have memory leaks - your Referenced `Activity` will not be GC

If you are using option 2 make sure you are using `Application Context`.

To init the singleton do something like:

```
getInstance(myActivity.getApplicationContext())
```

*option 1* is much better if the method is a utility method - does something and does not need to change it's state after the method has returned.

first of all you are not keeping a reference to `Context`. also you don't need to hold a singleton in the memory. [Last Static methods are efficient](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#PreferStatic).

Use option 2 if you are using the Singleton all the time and recreating objects during the process ([Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [RetroFit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) are good examples for the need of Singleton)

A good example of when to use a Singleton is [Android Volley library](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton). It's also relevant to fetching data from remote so have a look

Answer (score 1):

In essence, neither of your approaches are required for what you initially describe...

> I'm creating an application that for now consists of one activity and a widget. One of its functionality will be fetching some data from the internet. This data will only change every midnight, so there's no need to fetch this data every time you start the app or look at the widget.

So what exactly is going to be responsible for the daily download and how is it going to be triggered? Neither an `Activity` nor an App Widget is suitable.

Add a few bits and pieces - use `AlarmManager` to create a repeating alarm set for around midnight (it won't be exact but normally within a few seconds). Have the alarm trigger a broadcast which is received by a `BroadcastReceiver` and then have the receiver start an `IntentService` to download and save what's needed.

It's a win-win scenario. The alarm will be fired regardless of whether your app is 'running' or not (or whether the phone is asleep or not). The receiver will be triggered and the `IntentService` uses its own worker thread so no need to worry about any problems with running network code on the main/UI thread. Also, an `IntentService` has a `Context` which can be used to access `SharedPreferences` and will shut itself down after it has done its work.

Comment: I'm afraid I gave you wrong information. Later I found out the data is not necessarily updated around midnight, but some arbitrary time during the day (I will edit my question now; apologies). Can I still use an AlarmManager then?

Comment: @CamilStaps : By arbitrary are you saying the data will change at the server at random times each day (one interpretation of arbitrary) or that the time will be fixed each day but can be set by the user either at the server end or app end?

Comment: Sorry, at random times each day indeed, mostly during the afternoon. What I have in mind is that every time the data is requested, I check: is the cached data more than an hour old? If not, show cached data. If yes, fetch. But I don't want to fetch every hour, if the user doesn't use the app or the widget. (I have _this_ functionality already, I was just wondering what would be the correct OOP approach).

Comment: OK, you can put together a combo effect. When the user starts the Activity or uses the widget, check last update time - if it is more than an hour ago then check for an update from the server - if less than an hour since last use then don't worry. Either way, a daily update as I described would cover it if the user hasn't used the app for 24 hours or so. Alternatively, an alarm every 4 hours, 8 hours, 12 hours etc might be an option if the user hasn't used the app for a while.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I think I'm going with the other suggestion. It doesn't feel so neat to have an AlarmManager fetching the data every some hours if the user doesn't use the app that regularly (even though it's not that much data).